# Can we insert equations as images in IEEE format?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Can we insert equations as images in IEEE format? So instead the writing the equation in latex I will be inserting the image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. of course you can do that by including it as a graphic. But, please dont do that.

Comment: Unless you include it as a vector graphic, it will look absolutely terrible. And even if you do, it won’t look as good.

Comment: Even if you are trying to put a long equation across two columns, you can still use equations inside a figure* or table*.  Note that the equation numbers will be incremented immediately, not when the equation shows up.  You might need to use \tag and \stepcounter to get the numbering right.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Instead of using an `figure` environment, I think it is better to use `equation` environment with `\adjincludegraphics` from `adjustbox` package. That way, the equation will be handled normally including its numbering